# I need a way to wrap all my methods inside try catch 

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, lambda, try-catch

If there exists a way with which I could wrap all my methods inside try catch without writing try catch in every method.

Currently we are using the below mentioned approach:

```
public TValue ErrorHandler<TValue>(Func<TValue> action)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TValue)action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle Exception and Log it..........
            return default(TValue);
        }
    }

    public void ErrorHandler(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle Exception and Log it..........
        }
    }
```

and this is used as:

```
public void ClearControls()
    {
        this.ErrorHandler(() =>
        {
               //................................
        });
    }
```

Since this uses Lambda in it, it forces to run the application again if the code is edited while debugging.

Please let me know any other possible solution where I could implement Try Catch in all methods and debug my code without any pain.

Comment: I hope you don't really mean ALL of your methods. If you do this on ALL your methods, you are basically removing exception handling as a mechanism from your application. You do not want to do that.

Answer (score 4):

- Don't wrap *everything* in a `try-catch`.  Use `try-catch` in places
  where you might normally see an exception without having a bug in your code, such as an IO operation. If you wrap everything, that might actually make testing and debugging harder, resulting in lower quality code. Let the bugs bubble up and catch them early in development.
- Write a handler method that does the logging and all the other common things you want to do in `try-catch` and simply use that method in `catch` blocks.
- Use a global exception handler for logging exceptions unhandled by `try-catch` blocks by subscribing to the [AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Answer (score 3):

An [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) can help you here. There is a blog post about the `OnExceptionAspect` [here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-1-e28093-OnExceptionAspect.aspx).

Basically the net result, instead of putting the try-catch into your method, you decorate the method with an attribute (or aspect in this case).

Personally I'd never really use this, as I only try/catch on things that I can handle and have never needed things like per-method logging all throughout the app. If you can't handle it, don't catch it.

---

**Update:** Based on your comments, an alternative to PostSharp is [Castle DynamicProxy](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=DynamicProxy&NS=Tools&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), which is free. With regards to the PostSharp license, you should be able to get the behaviour you need from the free version, which covers method-level aspest as detailed [here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/purchase/compare).

Comment: Adam, I tried your way and I found in a link(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD) which portrays what I wanted to do. But the problem with this approach is that we need to inherit all the classes from ContextBoundObject. But System.Windows.Forms.Form cannot be inherited from the ContextBoundObject. Do you have any similar other way which could help out with my purpose. Also I cannot opt for PostSharp as this needs license and I cannot go for that as it is out of my budget. Please suggest any other alternative if you have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to catch the errors in the caller, or to take that a step further, the thread entry point which is usually your Program.cs or global.asax.cs.